# Three-phase AC motor LTspice simulation

Tags: motor, ac, ltspice

I am wondering if anyone has an idea of how I can model a three-phase AC motor in LTspice. I have linked the characteristics of the motor below and it will be connected to a three-phase inverter.

[image]

Comment: Have you taken classes in mechanical modelling? Because this might be hard otherwise.

Comment: You could model it as a three-phase AC source pretty easily. But if you want it to have motor dynamics etc, it might be pretty hard in LT spice. Or at least you would have to use features of LT spice I am not familiar with. What is your goal?

Comment: There are resources on the web if you care to dedicate a few minutes of your time. It might even be more worth to do it instead of waiting hours or days for an answer here. You could try searching [here](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/), as a start (registration needed, to avoid spammers, but it's free).

Comment: You appear to be asking for opinions (*I am wondering if anyone has an idea of how*) and that means your question is currently off-topic; you need to ask an improved question and explain what you are trying to achieve with your model/simulation.

Comment: Something like this https://nl.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/inductionmotor.html

Comment: Or this https://fr.maplesoft.com/search/index.aspx?q=3%20phases%20induction%20machine&btnG= or this ... http://www.spectrum-soft.com/news/spring2014/ac_motor.shtm